Give buttons an active styling for change content javascript
I am creating a section in Elementor that has five buttons. Each one changes the content inside an adjacent section using Javascript. The functioning code is:


var $ = jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-showme]').on('click', function() {
    var showme = $(this).attr('data-showme')

    $('.all-content').hide()
    $('#' + showme).show()
  })
})
.all-content {
  display: none;
}

#professionals-content {
  display: block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



There is also an attribute that doesn't seem to fit into this forum's code structure:
data-showme|ID-NAME-content

The attribute tells the content which button to respond to. I already have css code working to tell the button how to react to hover, but I couldn't get any css to make the button that is currently active to remain in a style, until another one is clicked and that one gains the active style. I know it likely requires javascript so I came here. I also want to make sure this only affects the buttons in this section, not the rest of the page - so I assume that will involve giving the buttons id's Something like what the hover code has:
selector a:hover {
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
}

How can I make this work?

What do you mean by active?

Ad some HTML, guessing what jQuery is doing is pointless.

Here I added a css class "active" that gets applied to the last button that was clicked.
You can use a jquery selector to locate and then remove active from the previously clicked button, if such a button exists.


var $ = jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-showme]').on('click', function() {

    // remove active from existing button, if it exists
    $('[data-showme].active').removeClass('active');
    // add active to this button
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var showme = $(this).attr('data-showme')

    $('.all-content').hide()
    $('#' + showme).show()
  })
})
.all-content {
  display: none;
}

#professionals-content {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-showme='s1'>b1</button>
<button data-showme='s2'>b2</button>
<button data-showme='s3'>b3</button>
<div id='s1' class='all-content'>s1</div>
<div id='s2' class='all-content'>s2</div>
<div id='s3' class='all-content'>s3</div>




You don't need JavaScript for this. In your CSS you can use either the next-sibling or the subsequent-sibling combinator (used in the example) to show or hide elements.
In the example I also use the :has() pseudo-class to find the input element, because the two combinators need to be use on elements that are siblings (on the same level in the DOM tree).


form[name="select"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: .5em;
}

form[name="select"] label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  outline: transparent thick solid;
}

form[name="select"] label:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

form[name="select"] label:has(input:checked) {
  background-color: gray;
}

form[name="select"] label:has(input:focus) {
  outline: green thick solid;
}

form[name="select"] input {
  /* hide the radio button, but still focusable */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

form[name="select"]:has(input)~div {
  display: none;
}

form[name="select"]:has(input:checked[value="1"])~div#content1 {
  display: block;
}

form[name="select"]:has(input:checked[value="2"])~div#content2 {
  display: block;
}

form[name="select"]:has(input:checked[value="3"])~div#content3 {
  display: block;
}
<form name="select">
  <label>R1<input type="radio" name="r" value="1" checked></label>
  <label>R2<input type="radio" name="r" value="2"></label>
  <label>R3<input type="radio" name="r" value="3"></label>
</form>
<div id="content1">Content 1</div>
<div id="content2">Content 2</div>
<div id="content3">Content 3</div>



